# how to load angular-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-bootstrap, oclazyload

Problem: I could not load the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` from `node_modules`

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-bootstrap' is not available!
>   You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If
>   registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the
>   second argument.

```
'use strict';

export default require('angular')
  .module('lazyApp', [
    require('angular-ui-router'), 'angular-bootstrap',
    // @TODO: It's a hack! https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/issues/179
    (() => {
      require('oclazyload');
      return 'oc.lazyLoad'
    })(),

    //require('angular-bootstrap',

    /*
     uncomment to move msg-store to bundle.js only instead
     of putting it in both: 3.bundle.js and 4.bundle.js
     */
    //require('commons/msg-store').name,
    require('./pages/home/home.routing').name,
    require('./pages/messages/messages.routing').name,
    //require('./pages/solr/solr.routing').name
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var app = angular.module('app', [
>     'ui.bootstrap'
> ```

Make sure the js script is loaded on file, if tyou use bower you can install with name

> ```
> bower install angular-bootstrap --save
> ```

and then locate that file and load it on page

Comment: but me i would load angular-bootstrap with requirejs with oclazyload